# Haskell - help understanding a function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, mapping

I have this mystery function that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
mystery :: [a] -> [[a]]
mystery [] = [[]]
mystery (x:xs) = sets ++ (map (x:) sets)
                 where sets = mystery xs
```

Here are some inputs with results:

```
mystery [1,2] returns [[],[2],[1],[1,2]]
mystery [1,2,3] returns [[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

By looking at the results I can see that its computing all the possible combinations of the numbers in the list, but not all the possible permuations...I think.

The trouble i'm having is actually going through the recursion and understanding how the function is getting those results.

I think I get the start of it --> mapping (1:) onto [2], yielding [1,2], but its at this point that I'm confused how the recursion works, and whether I'm still mapping (1:) or now (2:), and onto what exactly.

If anyone could please help me out by explaining step by step (using one of the examples provided) how this function works (with the map and sets recursion), that would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is a `homework` tag appropriate here?  It looks like homework.

Comment: It's actually not homework. Involved with school, yes, but not homework. I'm studying for a test on Haskell and trying to better understand this example.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell will perform what is known as lazy evaluation, meaning it will only work things out as it needs them from left to right (generally). So taking your example of `mystery [1, 2]`, Haskell will do the following:

```
sets ++ (map (x:) sets)
```

Which evaluates to:

```
mystery (2:[]) ++ (map (1:) sets)
```

At this point, we're calling `mystery (2:[])`

```
mystery ([]) ++ (map (2:) sets) ++ (map (1:) sets)
```

`mystery ([])` will return an empty list of lists

```
[[]] ++ (map (2:) sets) ++ (map (1:) sets)
[[]] ++ (map (2:) mystery []) ++ (map (1:) sets)
```

So now Haskell will try to apply the function `(2:)` on a list containing an empty list

```
[[]] ++ (2:[[]]) ++ (map (1:) sets)
[[]] ++ [[2]] ++ (map (1:) sets)
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) sets)
```

This is where things get a little more confusing.

```
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) mystery (2:[]))
```

That last `sets` will evaluate `mystery (2:[])`

```
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) (sets ++ (map (2:) sets)))
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) (mystery [] ++ (map (2:) sets))
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) ([[]] ++ (map (2:) mystery []))
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) ([[]] ++ (2:[[]]))
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) ([[]] ++ [[2]])
```

Now `(1:)` will be applied to a list which contains an empty list, and a list containing the 2:

```
[[], [2]] ++ (map (1:) ++ [[], [2]])
[[], [2]] ++ [[1], [1, 2]]
[[], [2], [1], [1, 2]]
```

The real meat of the operation is in those last two sections. Haskell creates a list like `[[], [2]]` and then appends one to the head of each list to form `[[1], [1, 2]]`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a thorough response! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

your mystery function is computes the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of its input.